# Mouse scroll event is getting triggered 2 times when the scroll offset reach the specified point

Tags: javascript, jquery

This issue is only happening with normal PC mouse. Whenever I am scrolling the mouse wheel, i am getting the scroll event triggered 2 times. As a result the alert box is popping 2 times. I have tried using Apple magic mouse and manual browser window scrolling bar there the issue is not appearing. I am using the below JQuery code to get the event. Can any one tell me what am missing here or am i doing this in a wrong way?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
                            
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(
                      '#ajax-posts').offset().top + $('#ajax-posts').
                        outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {

                                    alert('reached check point');

                                    $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "block");
                    
                    }

                });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a debounce function might be able to help you with your issue.This should remove any unnecessary scrolls that you're facing.We are using debounce to prevent the scrolling to trigger too frequently. I hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var debounceScroll = null;
    
      $(window).scroll(function () {
    
        if (debounceScroll != null) {
          clearTimeout(debounceScroll);
        }
    
        debounceScroll = setTimeout(function() {
          if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#ajax-posts').offset().top + $('#ajax-posts').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
    
            alert('reached check point');
    
            $("#lds-ripple").css("display", "block");
    
          }
        }, 100);
    
      });
    
    });
```

Comment: Note: there are more generic/reusable debounce functions available, but the concept is the same.